# download webpage in pdf format in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an image and a header.I need to download only these two elements as a pdf file.I am able to download it but the image is not coming completely in the pdf and the quality is also bad.

Please help me on how to get the full image and how to increase the quality.

my component.ts code is:

```
downloadpdf(){
        console.log("download pdf is getting called");

        var pdf = new jsPDF();
var elements = $(".breadcrumbbox").append(document.getElementById('in-building-container'));
var i = 0;

var recursiveAddHtml = function () {
    if (i < elements.length) {
        var x = 0, y = i * 20; 
        pdf.addHTML(elements.get(i), x, y, function () {
            i++;
            recursiveAddHtml();
        });
    } else {
        pdf.save("building.pdf");
    }
}
```